# JSON Deserialization Array

Tags: rest-api, rest

I need help parsing the completedetails array from below JSON object and store it in a lead object

Below is the sample JSON Object

```
 {
            "request": {
                    "Details": {
                            "Owner": null,
                            "Investor": null,
                            "LOB": null,
                            "Agreement": null,
                            "location": [
                                    {
                                            "city": null,
                                          "Zip": null
                    }            
                ],
                            "Acceptence": null,
                            "Completedetails": [
                                    {
                                       "Name": null,
                                       "FirstName": null,
                                       "Phone": null,
                                       "Lastname" : null                                                 
                    }            
                ],
                            "id": null,
                            "Other": {
                                    "Value": null                            
                },
                            "Description": null,
                              "Object1": {
                                                
                },
                            "totalamount": null,
                            "totalamount1": null        
            }    
        } 
    }
```

Below is the apex method

```
Global class test{
       @HttpPost
   global static String Detailslist() {
  List<Details> Detailslist = new List<Details>();
   RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
   Blob jsonBlob = req.requestBody;
   String jsonString = jsonBlob.toString();

  //I need to deserialize/Parse the Completedetails array from the JSON above, perform Post/patch operation and store it in lead object.

   global class Details {
   public String Name;
   Public String FirstName;
   Public String LastName;
   Public String Phone;                                      
}    
}
```

I'm unable to use implicit deserialization for the completedatails array. 
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully this will help you http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Before using json2apex, replacing the "null" values with typical example values will allow that tool to infer the field types to be string or boolean or number and so leave you with less work in your code,

Comment: @KeithC  : I'm already having existing code for which I'm looking to merge the existing. JSON. Deserialize function is returning me null values, I need help with the syntax.    (Details)JSON.deserialize(jsonString,Details.class)) is what I'm using now.

Comment: @highfive ^^^^^